# SQL Server Reporting: How calculate value based on the previous calculated value int the same column?

Tags: expression, calculated-field, ssrs-2016, reporting-services-2016

I'm trying to calculate a row value based on the previous row value in the same column within a report expression. I can't precalculate this from database since starting point of calculation is dependent from input parameters and values in a table should be recalculated dynamically within report itself.

In Excel analogical data and formula look like as it is shown below (starting point is always 100):

```
   B      C             D            E
   Price  PreviousPrice CalcValue    Formula
1  NULL   NULL          100 
2  2.6    2.5           104          B2/C2*D1
3  2.55   2.6           102          B3/C3*D2
4  2.6    2.55          104          B4/C4*D3
5  2.625  2.6           105          B5/C5*D4
6  2.65   2.625         106          B6/C6*D5
7  2.675  2.65          107          B7/C7*D6
```

I tried to calculate expected values ("CalcValue" is the name of column where expression is set) like this:

`=Fields!Price.Value/ PreviousPrice.Value * Previous(reportitems("CalcValue").Value))`

but got an error "Aggregate functions can be used only on report items contained in page headers and footers"

Can you please advice whether expected result is achievable in my case and suggest a solution?

Thank you in advance!

Sadly I'm still facing with issue: calculated column does not consider previous calculated value. E.g., I added CalcVal field with 100 as default and tried to calculate using above approach, like: `=previous(runningValue(Fields!CalcVal.Value, sum, "DataSet1") ) * Fields!Price.Value/Fields!PreviousPrice.Value.`

But in this case it always multiples `Fields!Price.Value/Fields!PreviousPrice.Value` by 100..
 For example CalcVal on Fly always show 200 
`=previous(runningValue(Fields!CalcVal.Value, sum, "DataSet1")) * 2`

https://i.stack.imgur.com/mKlKQ.jpg

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I tried with your sample data, here is how I achieved the results

[image]

[image]

Formula to use, You might have to take care of null values

```
  =Fields!Price.Value/(Fields!PreviousPrice.Value*Previous(Fields!CalcValue.Value))
```

Edit: Update to answer after Op's comment

[image]

[image]

[image]

CalcValue is caluated with below formula i.e on the fly

```
=RunningValue(CountDistinct("Tablix6"),Count,"Tablix6"*100
```

and then Final value as below

```
=Fields!Price.Value/(Fields!PreviousPrice.Value*
Previous(RunningValue(CountDistinct("Tablix6"),Count,"Tablix6"))*100)
```

Comment: unfortunately it does not work for me:  the issue in this case is that CalcValue is not a column of dataset and initially does not have values (has to be calculated starting from 100 on a fly as a target column)

Comment: ahh still no worries, as you said CalcValue is calculated on the fly, just put that formula instead of Field!CalcValue.Value from my formula.
Note: You need previous value of CalcValue for your calculation, so have to adjust the formula.

Comment: thanks for your efforts AnkUser! 
but CalcValue is not supposed to be just cumulative by 100 (100 is only for the first row every time as default);

 every time this value need to be changed according to prior calculated one;  please look at formula example in my original message to see expected calculation logic

Comment: I have just used sample data to show you can perform your  formulas as such  B2/C2*D1.
You now have Idea how to get correct calculations even when your CalcValue is generated on the fly.
Use this Idea to generate your results

Comment: Sadly I'm still facing with issue: calculated column does not consider previous calculated value.
E.g., I added CalcVal field with 100 as default and tried to calculate using above approach, like:
 

=previous(runningValue(Fields!CalcVal.Value, sum, "DataSet1") )
* Fields!Price.Value/Fields!PreviousPrice.Value. 

But in this case it always multiples 
Fields!Price.Value/Fields!PreviousPrice.Value by 100..

For example CalcVal on  Fly always show 200  
= previous(runningValue(Fields!CalcVal.Value, sum, "DataSet1")) * 2

https://imgur.com/Wtg3Wsg

Sorry for bad formatting..

Comment: You are getting it wrong. I just showed you example tha with expression value I.e on the fly values could also be used in your final calculation. Now with runningvalues function I am getting distinct row number for each row of a  tablix like 1,2,3,.. and then just multiplying with 100 so that I get 101,102,.. but in your original data you already have calcValue been calculated. So just for your simplicity create one more column in ssrs and show there previous value of your calcvalue. Once you do that you could slowly figure out how to use that in your final calculations.

Comment: But I dont have calcValue calculated originally - it has only default 100 as first value for further calculations and I can't achieve expected result just by referring to previous value since need calculated previous value